# Is there a Python module that can be used to insert animated GIF files into Excel

Tags: python, excel, gif, xlsxwriter

In Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.13929.20206), animated GIF files can be inserted. After inserting, they are playable, even after saving and closing the file. The process for inserting GIFs in Excel is fairly simple: Activate the Insert tab, choose the Pictures option, browse to the file and choose Insert.

Although it's fairly simple to manually insert files into an Excel workbook, I could benefit greatly from a Python script that automates the process. I've tried to accomplish this using `xlsxwriter` and the `insert_image` method to no avail. Here is a brief sample of code, followed by the error that is thrown:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.insert_image('B2', '001.gif')
workbook.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/Software/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 304, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "/opt/Software/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 634, in _store_workbook
    self._prepare_drawings()
  File "/opt/Software/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 1084, in _prepare_drawings
    self._get_image_properties(filename, image_data)
  File "/opt/Software/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 1192, in _get_image_properties
    "%s: Unknown or unsupported image file format." % filename)
xlsxwriter.exceptions.UnsupportedImageFormat: 001.gif: Unknown or unsupported image file format.
```

Clearly, the `insert_image` method does not support GIF files.

I have scoured the forums, but can't find any other modules or methods that will allow me to perform this simple task in Python.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: I am the author of XlsxWriter. The reason GIF files aren't supported is that animated GIFs weren't supported by Excel and no-one had much interest in the non-animated kind. If Excel now supports animated gifs then I am open to adding support for GIFs to XlsxWriter. You could open a feature request on Github. In the meantime I believe OpenPyXL supports GIF as an image format.

Comment: Thank you, @jmcnamara. OpenPyXL seems to do the trick.

Comment: I added support for GIF images (and by extension animated GIFs) in XlsxWriter version 1.4.2. Can you try that with you example above and if it works as expected (it should) then update one of your posts to indicate that it works with version >= 1.4.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@jmcnamara suggested using the OpenPyXL module. The following Python code will accomplish the necessary task:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

#Define the Excel workbook and sheet.
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

#Locate the GIF.
img = Image('000.gif')

#Add the GIF to the worksheet.
ws.add_image(img)

#Save the workbook.
wb.save('out.xlsx')
```